# How to Make a Linked List That Represents an Integer in C++? (LeetCode Add Two Numbers)

Tags: c++, linked-list

Here is my in-progress solution to the "Add Two Numbers" problem on LeetCode:

```
    /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) 
{
        int tenPower = 0; 
        
        int num1 = listToNum(l1); 
        int num2 = listToNum(l2); 
        
        //cout << "Finished listToNum."; 
        
        int sum = num1 + num2; 
    
        ListNode currentNode = ListNode(sum%10); 
        ListNode* sumNodePtr = &currentNode; 
        sum /= 10; 
        
        while (sum/10!=0)
        {
            ListNode nextNode = ListNode(sum%10); 
            currentNode.next=&nextNode; 
            currentNode = nextNode; 
            cout << "Here"; 
            sum /= 10; 
        }
        
        currentNode.next = nullptr; 
        
        return sumNodePtr;  
    }
    
    int listToNum (ListNode* l)
    {
        int num = 0;
        int tenPower = 0; 
        
        do 
        {
            num += l->val*pow(10,tenPower); 
            l = l->next; 
        } while (l!=nullptr);
        
        return num;
    }
};
```

I am getting an "UndefinedBahaviorSanitizer" error. the problem arises in the while loop in the addTwoNumbers function and has to do with pointers I'm sure. However, to my knowledge it looks to me like I am handling the pointers correctly. Since I'm obviously not, I'd really like to know what's gone wrong and hopefully come away with some stronger knowledge about pointers in C++.

How would one better construct a linked list of integers? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ListNode* sumNodePtr = &currentNode; ` is a pointer to a local variable. After the `return` this pointer becomes dangling

Comment: And you have the same issue in `currentNode.next=&nextNode; `

Comment: `num += l->val*pow(10,tenPower);` -- You shouldn't use floating point functions such as `pow` to solve integer-based problems.  Converting a number from digits is done much more easily than your `listToNum` function.

Comment: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is a linked list, you don't have to reinvent a wheel

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Sentinel Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), this'd pass without an Undefined Behavior on LeetCode and with less statements:

```
static const struct Solution {
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* list_a, ListNode* list_b) {
        ListNode sentinel(0);
        ListNode* ptr = &sentinel;
        int carry = 0;

        while (list_a || list_b || carry) {
            if (list_a) {
                carry += list_a->val;
                list_a = list_a->next;
            }

            if (list_b) {
                carry += list_b->val;
                list_b = list_b->next;
            }

            ptr->next = new ListNode(carry % 10);
            carry /= 10;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        return sentinel.next;
    }
};
```

Apart from that, `listToNum` is a pretty odd helper. We don't have to do that. We can simply traverse the lists and do the sum.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a much nicer solution and introduced me to how to use a sentinel node.

Comment: I think I came to my overcomplicated solution by thinking that adding two numbers backwards was more complex than it really is. If we get a carry digit, we just add it to the digit to the right instead of left as usual. If we don't, then we just add like normal.